# How to read a table that is in one database into a query that is running on different database in Synapse pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse-pipeline

There are 2 databases, say Database A and Database B. I got a query that is running on Database A, now I need to join to a table (~20 rows) that resides in Database B and filter the result based on values coming from the table that is in Database B.

Example: Table in Database B, say table name is 'city'

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dallas |
| 2 | Houston |
| 3 | Tampa |

**Query Running on Database A:**

`select * from DatabaseA.city a  inner join DatabaseB.city b on a.[ID] = b.[ID]  where b.ID = 3 and b.City = 'Tampa'`

How do I replicate this scenario in Synapse pipeline?

**Approach 1**: I have tried using a Lookup activity to read the table from Database B and in the query that is running on Database A I have created a temp table and attempted to insert the data from the Lookup into the temp table but was unsuccessful as I can only select using an integer index.

**Approach 2**: I have tried using Lookup activity to read the table from Database B and use  STRING_AGG function to form comma separated list of values for each column from the table and within the query that will be run on Database A, I have tried creating a temp table and attempted to insert the values by using STRING_SPLIT and CROSS_APPLY but I couldn't get that working either, ended up in cartesian join result.

Is there a better approach to implement this scenario?

Note: This is scenario is simple to implement in a Data Flow using JOIN but in my environment we are only using synapse pipelines to move the data.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate the query in ADF, follow the below approach.

First take the table from database B(table with less than 5000 rows) in a lookup activity with the below query.

```
select * from cityB where ID=3 and City='Tampa'
```

[image]

From my sample data, upon debugging till this activity, it will give a JSON of type Array of objects like below.

```
[
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "City": "Tampa",
            "fname": "Virat"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "City": "Tampa",
            "fname": "Rakesh"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "City": "Tampa",
            "fname": "Starc"
        }
]
```

Take copy activity and database A table as source for it. Use the above lookup activity output in the database A table query like below.

```
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@{activity('Lookup on B').output.value}';

select * from cityA a  inner join (select * from openjson(@json1,'$') with(
    ID int,
    City varchar(32),
    fname varchar(32)
)) b on a.[ID]=b.[ID];
```

[image]

Give your target table in the sink. The above query produces the duplicate columns `ID`. Copy activity will give the error for duplicate input columns. So, remove the extra column in the copy activity mapping.

First Go to **Mapping** -> **import schema**. Now it will ask the lookup output array.

[image]

Give the above array in it and click on ok. It will show all input column mappings. In that remove the extra `ID` column and map the target mapping as per your requirement.

[image]

Now, debug the entire pipeline and it will copy the expected data into the target table.

[image]

Comment: Great, it worked for you.